# R / Index lower triangle vector by pairwise indices

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, geometry, symmetric

I am looking for a way to index a lower triangle vector of a symmetric matrix by pairwise indices in the language **R**. Here is some explanatory code:

#### Background

`M` is an `n` times `n` pairwise matrix, here with random data (just to show):

```
n <- 5
set.seed(0815)
M <- matrix(sample(n^2),n,n)
M[upper.tri(M)] <- t(M)[upper.tri(M)]
diag(M) <- 0
M

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    6    3   18   10
# [2,]    6    0   11   23    9
# [3,]    3   11    0    5   21
# [4,]   18   23    5    0   16
# [5,]   10    9   21   16    0
```

#### Data

My data (`x`) is the lower triangle vector from the matrix `M`:

```
x <- M[lower.tri(M)]
```

And the index pairs I want to extract is stored in a vector named `i`:

```
i <- c(2:3,5)
```

#### Aim

My aim is now to extract the pairs from the lower triangle vector as in the following matrix example.

```
aim <- M[i,i][lower.tri(M[i,i])]
aim
# [1] 11  9 21
```

#### My Solution

Since in my case `M` is not available and I don't want to generate it from `x` (memory issue), I created the following indexing function `f`:

```
f <- function (n,i) {
  r <- combn(i,2)[1,]
  c <- combn(i,2)[2,]
  n * r + c - (r * (r + 1))/2 - n
}
```

#### The Result

```
res <- x[f(n,i)]
identical(res, aim)
# [1] TRUE
```

#### Finally, my question:

Is there a **more elegant** or already **builtin** version in R of the function `f`, maybe one that also does not need `n` as argument, calculating it from the length of `x`?

Thank you in advance.

Sven

Comment: You might want to look for solution to extracting particular entries within r distance "matrices" since they are stored as the values in lower triangular order. (I'm not aware of a C-implemented function, but you might think about restricting your search to answers that also included Rcpp strategies.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like your best best is to use something from the `Matrix` library to store your original matrix. It has several nice features which I expect could make dealing with matrices like this quite easier.

Here I use a `dtpMatrix` (dense, triangular, packed, matrix), without the diagonal. This takes the same amount of space in memory as your `x` plus just a little more for keeping track of the matrix size, etc. By using this you can refer to the rows and columns in the usual way. I then can take the desired rows and columns from your `i`, note though that the `-1` is needed because I'm not storing the diagonal. Also notice that the `@x` returns just the lower triangular part of the matrix, because that's how it's stored internally.

```
library(Matrix)
k <- length(x)
n <- as.integer(((sqrt(8 * k + 1) + 1) / 2) - 1)
M2 <- new("dtpMatrix", uplo="L", diag="N", Dim=c(n, n), x=x)
M2[i[-1] - 1, i[-length(i)]]@x
## [1] 11  9 21
```

As an aside, note that this also calculates the `n` from the length of `x`, as mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I thought about the `Matrix` package and it's support for sparse matrices but haven't known about `dtpMatrix` yet. An `Rcpp` solution is maybe my preferred choice since it is already a dependency for my project. But I will compare both.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this again I'm puzzled that you didn't just do:

```
x[i]
#[1]  3 18 11
```

If you didn't want the intermediate value assigned to `x` you could just use:

```
M[lower.tri(M)][i]
#[1]  3 18 11
```

Comment: The aim is `c(11,9,21)`, not `c(3,18,11)`.

Comment: Thanks for your try @BondedDust, but as @Aaron mentioned, it is not the expected result. Also `M` is not available and creating it from `x` would need the memory to be relocalized and ±doubled.